# How to dynamically change a Livewire Component contents with blade templates properly?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I am working on a Laravel project using Livewire to build UIs. I'm making a form which can change its fields based on the user input from a collection of buttons. Each form option is made in 5 blade templates which are included dynamically based on the users choice.

The problem is when the user changes the form and then fills in the fields, it returns an error from Str::studly, which strangely gets an empty string.

After further investigations, once the form is changed, when a value inside it is updated, it sends the value back to the components controller, but with a null key, like so:

[A screen from the stacktrace after the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV9GR.png)

It ultimately sends it again with the right key, but when it happens the component's controller already crashed.

## What didn't work

I tried to apply `$this->reset()` when I'm changing the components contents / the form fields to reload the whole component, but it resets the fields values and does not reload the whole component.

I ultimately tried to remove the `@include` directives and put all the templates in one file, but it happens again.

Here's a sample of my code handling the different includes (is it bad practice? If yes, how to improve it?):

```
@if (!session('typeBien'))
            
@elseif (session('typeBien') == 'maison')
    @include('livewire.inscription.maison')
@elseif (session('typeBien') == 'appartement')
    @include('livewire.inscription.appartement')
@elseif (session('typeBien') == 'terrain')
    @include('livewire.inscription.terrain')
@elseif (session('typeBien') == 'parking')
    @include('livewire.inscription.parking')
@elseif (session('typeBien') == 'autre')
    @include('livewire.inscription.autre')
@endif
```

I'm an apprentice in web development, I searched on Livewire's docs, googled and even asked chatGPT to solve this issue, but I found nothing. Am I doing it wrong? Or is it a Livewire's edge cases?

Comment: So, you load different Livewire components based on a session variable. And this session variable changes "actively" while a user is on the page?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, it changes when the user clicks on a button. The button calls a method from the component which changes the value of `typeBien` and triggers a render of the component. I fixed it atm by using a whole new Livewire component for every `@include`, but i saw in the docs that this not the recommended way to do it, but i don't know how to solve this issue by another way, any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I think the best solution here would be what Rey has suggested, an adaptive Livewire form. Using session variables actively doesn't sound like a good idea. You could even go as far as having array vars named after your type (e.g. `public array $maison = []`, after which you can just call `$this->{$type}` when you're submitting and have easy access to the data per type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will entirely answer your question, but may give you some other options of achieving what you need (assuming I understand what your goal is correctly).

Livewire can do a lot of the work for you (for example using a `$type_bien` variable instead of `session()`.

The examples below have buttons which call an `updateType` function in the livewire component, which can be used to hide/show the partial forms.

I have used `components` instead of `includes` for the form partials.

Personally, unless the form has many fields (or the components are used elsewhere), I see no harm in just including the `<input>` fields directly in your livewire blade (you could then do something like `{{ $type_bien === 'maison' ?? 'display:none;' }}`, or choose to not render the element at all.

Just some ideas, I hope this helps you in some way :)

#### Livewire Component

```php
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class TestForm extends Component
{
    public string $type_bien = 'maison'; // Default on page load

    // Your input fields (if you want them in Livewire)
    public string $name = ''; // Default on page load
    public string $tel = ''; // Default on page load
    public string $email = ''; // Default on page load

    protected $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|min:3',
        'tel' => 'required|min:9',
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ];

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.test-form')
            ->layout('layouts.admin');
    }

    public function updateType($type) {
        $this->type_bien = $type;
    }

    public function submit()
    {
        // Validates against the $rules above
        $this->validate();

        // Save data example
        Model::create([
            'name' => $this->name,
            'tel' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
        ]);
    }

}
```

#### Livewire Blade

```php
<div>
    <div class="btn-container">
        <div class="btn btn-blue btn-outline" wire:click="updateType('maison')">
            Maison
        </div>
        <div class="btn btn-blue btn-outline" wire:click="updateType('appartement')">
            Appartement
        </div>
        <div class="btn btn-blue btn-outline" wire:click="updateType('terrain')">
            Terrain
        </div>
    </div>
    @if($errors->any())
        @foreach($errors as $error)
            <p>
                {{ $error }}
            </p>
        @endforeach
    @endif
    <form wire:submit.prevent="submit">
        @switch($type_bien)
            @case('maison')
                <x-form-partial.maison />
                @break
            @case('appartement')
                <x-form-partial.appartement />
                @break
            @case('terrain')
                <x-form-partial.terrain />
                @break
            @default
             ??
        @endswitch
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-green btn-outline" type="submit">
                Save
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

#### components/form-partial/maison.blade.php

```php
<input type="text" class="form-input" wire:model="name">
<input type="text" class="form-input" wire:model="tel">
<input type="text" class="form-input" wire:model="email">
```

##### Removing Switch

Rather than using a switch statement, you could also do something like this.

```php
<form wire:submit.prevent="submit">
    ...
    @component('components.form-partial.'.$type_bien) @endcomponent
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-green btn-outline" type="submit">
            Save
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

```php
public function updateType($type) {
    // Protect against users modifying the page, else you will get an error of 'component not found'
    $allowed_types = ['maison', 'appartement', 'terrain'];
    if (in_array($type, $allowed_types, true)) {
        $this->type_bien = $type;
    } else {
        $this->type_bien = 'maison'; // Default
    }
}
```